# Change Flutter theme at runtime

Tags: flutter

I tried to change the theme of my Flutter app at runtime with a simple button press.

I wanted to do this by using a theme widget in the page where I can adjust the theme variable (via setState).

The problem is that the new theme loads, but the colours in the app are not adjusted. This means that, for example, the old primary colour is still used.

i have no idea what i am doing wrong here as i am still very new to flutter

My code is as follows:

My class with the Widget:

```
class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  const Onboarding({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _OnboardingState();
}

class _OnboardingState extends State<Onboarding> {
var prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
ThemeData baseTheme = ThemeProvider().themeRed;
ThemeColors _color = ThemeColors.red;

@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    prefs.then((value) => {
          setState(() {
            color = value.getString("color") ?? "blue";
            baseTheme = ThemeProvider().getThemeByName(color);
          })
        });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: baseTheme,
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 15,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            bottom: const TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                    child: Text(
                  "Neu",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
                Tab(
                    child: Text(
                  "Wiederkehrender Spieler",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
                newbie(context),
                returning(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//more widgets following here, but should be unimportant

onColorChanged() {
    switch (_color) {
      case ThemeColors.red:
        color = "red";
        break;
      case ThemeColors.blue:
        color = "blue";
        break;
      case ThemeColors.green:
        color = "green";
        break;
      case ThemeColors.yellow:
        color = "yellow";
        break;
      case ThemeColors.purple:
        color = "purple";
        break;
      case ThemeColors.orange:
        color = "orange";
        break;
    }

    setState(() {
      baseTheme = ThemeProvider().getThemeByName(color);
      print(color);
    });
  }
```

The Theme Provider looks as follows

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData getThemeByName(String color) {
    print(color);
    switch (color) {
      case "red":
        return themeRed;

      case "blue":
        return themeBlue;

      case "green":
        return themeGreen;

      case "yellow":
        return themeYellow;

      case "purple":
        return themePurple;

      case "orange":
        return themeOrange;
    }
    return themeRed;
  }

  ThemeData themeRed = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
    background: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.88),
    primary: Colors.red,
    secondary: Colors.grey,
  ));

  ThemeData themeBlue = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
        background: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.88),
        primary: Colors.blue,
        secondary: Colors.grey,
      ));
ThemeData themeGreen = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
        background: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.88),
        primary: Colors.green,
        secondary: Colors.grey,
      ));

  ThemeData themeYellow = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
        background: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.88),
        primary: Colors.yellow,
        secondary: Colors.grey,
      ));

  ThemeData themePurple = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
        background: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.88),
        primary: Colors.purple,
        secondary: Colors.grey,
      ));

  ThemeData themeOrange = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
        background: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.88),
        primary: Colors.orange,
        secondary: Colors.grey,
      ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to change the app theme, you should change the state of `MaterialApp`. So, you should place your state consumer accordingly.

In order to reach the theme `ValueNotifier` in any class or widget, we should use this as an instance. This way:

```
class ThemeStuff {
  static ThemeStuff? _instance;

  static ThemeStuff get instance {
    _instance ??= ThemeStuff._init();

    return _instance!;
  }

  ThemeStuff._init() {
    theme.value = darkBlueTheme;
  }

  ValueNotifier<ThemeData> theme = ValueNotifier<ThemeData>(ThemeData.dark());

  void updateValue(ThemeData themes) {
    theme.value = themes;
    print(theme.value);
  }

  // here you can create infinite number of theme by the way

  ThemeData darkAmberTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.amber,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  );

  ThemeData darkBlueTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  );

  ThemeData darkRedTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  );

  ThemeData lightTealTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.tealAccent,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.tealAccent,
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 22)),
  );
}
```

Then use its `ValueListenableBuilder` at `MaterialApp`:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ThemeStuff appValueNotifier = ThemeStuff.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: appValueNotifier.theme,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: const Home(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: value,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And let's change it anywhere you want:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ThemeStuff appValueNotifier = ThemeStuff.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Flutter"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CupertinoButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: const Text("dark blue"),
                onPressed: () {
                  appValueNotifier.updateValue(appValueNotifier.darkBlueTheme);
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              CupertinoButton(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: const Text("dark amber"),
                onPressed: () {
                  appValueNotifier.updateValue(appValueNotifier.darkAmberTheme);
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              CupertinoButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Text("dark red"),
                onPressed: () {
                  appValueNotifier.updateValue(appValueNotifier.darkRedTheme);
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              CupertinoButton(
                color: Colors.teal,
                child: const Text("light teal"),
                onPressed: () {
                  appValueNotifier.updateValue(appValueNotifier.lightTealTheme);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: That Solution is Perfect thank you so much.